# Show only the first and last y-axis label on a graph highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, label

For a graph I would like to show only the labels that belong to the first value and the last value.

I tried to get the last value via an event trigger. Unfortunately, this only works for the last value and not the first value. I also don't know how to do this for both series. So far I only manage for series [0].

```
  chart: {
    type: 'line',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this,
          points = chart.series[0].points,
          lastValue,
          chosenPointlast;

        points.forEach(function(point, index) {
          if (!lastValue || lastValue < point.x) {
            lastValue = point.x;
            chosenPointlast = point;
          }
        }); 

        chosenPointlast.update({
          marker: {
            enabled: true,
            fillColor: 'orange'
          },
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: 'orange'
          },
        });
      }
    }
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Monthly Average Temperature'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Temperature (°C)'
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    line: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false
      },
      enableMouseTracking: false
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
  }, {
    name: 'London',
    data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
  }]
});
```

So I hope to see labels 7.0 and 9.6 for series [0] and 3.9 and 4.8 for series [1]. Hopefully you can help me with this. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pension007/p5dgq1aw/29/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the 4 edge points of one serie in this way:

```
const pointsSortedByY = serie.points.sort((p1, p2) => p2.y - p1.y);
const top = pointsSortedByY[0];
const bottom = pointsSortedByY[pointsSortedByY.length - 1];

const pointsSortedByX = serie.points.sort((p1, p2) => p2.x - p1.x);
const first = pointsSortedByX[0];
const last = pointsSortedByX[pointsSortedByX.length - 1];
```

then you can print it:

```
[top,bottom, first, last].forEach(function (point) {
    point.update({
        marker: {
            enabled: true,
            fillColor: 'green'
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            color: 'green'
        }
    });
},this);
```

and finally repeat the same operation for each series:

```
chart1.series.forEach(function (serie) {
    printTopAndBottom(serie);
}, this);
```

This is the result:
[image: Result]

https://jsfiddle.net/7ue8ow0b/

Comment: Thanks @gixlg this is exactly what i was looking for. Thanks again!!